# Time-independent vector field

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions, vector-fields

In a time-independent vector field I want to draw streamlines, path and streak lines.

Given $v_x=-x$ and $v_y=y$, how should I draw them ?

Comment: How have you tried to draw them

Comment: I do not know how to begin drawing them.

Comment: http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~mwheeler/fa12/math200/plotting_fields.html